# Create inherited class from type parameter

Tags: c#, class, generics, inheritance

I have a generic controller to which I pass a class containing only properties. It all works great but...

I want to create another class in the Controller class that inherits the passed class.

Sort of like this:

```
public class Products
{
    public Int32 ProductID {get; set;}
    public String ProductName {get; set;}
}

public class ProductController : Controller<Products>
{
    public ProductsController() : base("Products", "ProductID", "table", "dbo")
    {
    }
}

public class Controller<T> : IDisposable where T : new()
{
    protected Controller(String tablename, String keyname, String entitytype, String tableschema = "dbo")
    {
        ...
    }

    //How do I create the Recordset class inheriting T
    public class Recordset : T   //<----This is what I don't know how to do
    {
        public Int32 myprop {get; set;}

        public void MoveNext()
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

How do I create the class Recordset using T as inherited?

Comment: did you try also including the `where T : class, new()`?  You can't inherit structs.

Comment: @Chris: Take a look at `ImpromptuInterface` on Nuget which can create new types on the fly that act like other types; but you *really* don't want to go there. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: Thanks, Berin. That was it. Thought I did this before but...solution below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class Controller<T> : IDisposable where T : class, new()
{
    protected Controller(String tablename, String keyname, String entitytype, String tableschema = "dbo")
    {
        ...
    }
   public class Recordset<TT> where TT : class, new()   
    {
        public TT myinheritedclass {get; set}
        public Int32 myprop {get; set;}

        public void MoveNext()
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }

    public Recordset<T> myRecordset = new Recordset<T>()
}
```

Comment: This is composition not inheritance.   How would you shim the contracts for type being mapped?  You are better off with D.I. or Emit.

Comment: Nah. Been working perfectly for 5 years. I've used this construct thousands of times now and it works exactly the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler [won't let you do that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f47cb6h7.aspx) (as I'm sure the error message told you):

> **Cannot derive from 'identifier' because it is a type parameter**
> Base classes or interfaces for generic classes cannot be specified by a type parameter. Derive from a specific class or interface, or a specific generic class instead, or include the unknown type as a member.

You could use composition instead of inheritance:

```
public class Controller<T> : IDisposable where T : new()
{
    public class RecordSet 
    {    
        private T Records;
    
        public RecordSet(T records)
        {
            Records = records;
        }        

        public void MoveNext()
        {
            // pass through to encapsulated instance
            Records.MoveNext();
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's a nested class, so it gets that for "free" - it's a `Controller<T>.RecordSet`

Comment: Ah, I had assumed OP had just messed up the brackets.

Comment: Nope! No bracket issue! :)

Comment: Side note: "can't" is a bit too strong - if one really wants to do that than with some IL generation it can be achieved... but for anyone but small subset of C# developers it is really outside of they expertise/realm of possible.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The OP marked his question as `C#`. If the C# spec forbids it, I think that is an answer.

Comment: @Aron can you please point to section of C# spec that *prohibits* creation of types at run time? (I don't see strict requirement of particular syntax in the question - the way it shown seem to be very compact easy to read explanation of the goal to me, but possibly not exact syntax/approach)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I had assumed that was where the link pointed to...assumed based on what Jon Skeet would have done >_<

Comment: The spec is not available online except as a downloadable word document, so I can't link directly to the section, but "A type parameter cannot be used directly to declare a base class (§10.2.4) or interface (§13.1.3)." - from the  [C# specification 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)

Comment: Of course, that still doesn't preclude shenanigans with Reflection.Emit.

Comment: "You could use encapsulation instead of inheritance".  It is not called 'encapsulation' it is referred to as 'composition'.  See GoF design patterns to get around multiple inheritance bottlenecks.

Comment: @Latency I no longer remember writing this answer, but thanks for the catch, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using classes under Reflection.Emit namespace. but if you are digging that far youll probably find out you dont need inheritence.

Comment: Care to give an example?

Thanks!

Comment: I agree with this.. TypeBulder, ExpressionTrees, Code DOM.  However, you may want to look into 'dependency injection' topics for this as well.